# Would a question about "Finding Nemo" be welcome in Movies & TV stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I've been wanting to ask a question about the movie "Finding Nemo" but was unsure if the question would be welcome on this site.  Would it be welcomed on this site, or is it better suited on another stack exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that *Finding Nemo* is very well a movie in every way, I don't see a reason why a question about it would be off-topic right away. But of course it depends on the particular question if it ultimately is on-topic or not and for that you might also want to consult the [respective section of the help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But in general **proper questions about *Finding Nemo* or any other animated movie are as welcome as questions about any other movie**.